# Programmatically test if a MS Access database is encrypted

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on automating the release of new versions of our MS Access application.

We cannot ship the database unencrypted, so I want to add a test that will display a msgbox with a warning that the database is not encrypted.

Does anyone know the object/property I can test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it by creating a user defined function. Write below function in a module or form module.

```
Public Function IsDbSecured(ByVal sDb As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim oAccess         As Access.Application
 
    Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    oAccess.Visible = False
 
    'If an error occurs below, the db is password protected
    oAccess.DBEngine.OpenDatabase sDb, False
 
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    oAccess.Quit acQuitSaveNone
    Set oAccess = Nothing
    Exit Function
 
Error_Handler:
    If Err.Number = 3031 Then
        IsDbSecured = True
         Else
        MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```

Then call it from a button or your desired way like this.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim fileTestPath As String

    'Change your database path here.
    fileTestPath = "C:\Users\Harun.Rashid\Documents\Test_Close.accdb"

    If IsDbSecured(fileTestPath) = True Then
        MsgBox "Your database is encrypted by password"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good answer! After I run your test it leaves an Access Db open on my desktop with the "Password Required" dialog. Any idea how to prevent that or automatically close it?

Comment: Password require box shouldn’t visible as visible property is `False`. Can you please post your code. How you are using it?

Comment: I copied your function and subroutine to the end of my global module in my Access app/db. changed the fileTestPath. Then did F8 to run the subroutine.

Comment: Run the code from a form to test. Add a `Command Button` to a form and then call the function from that command button as I seen in screenshot.